# Ornstein-Uhlenbeck and Stationarity

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I'm taking a Statistical Mechanics course and we just started discussing the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process. I'm confused by what seems to be two contradictory facts about this process. For one, it is Gaussian, Markov, and Stationary. Stationary, as I currently understand it, means the moments of its distribution do not vary with time and, specifically, the autocorrelation function doesn't vary with time. On the other hand, [Doob's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoobsTheorem.html) shows that any Markov and Gaussian process has a correlation function which is proportional to $e^{-t}$. But this would suggest the correlation function does vary with time, meaning it isn't stationary.

What false assumption am I making that leads to this contradiction?

Comment: I think stationary in this context means that the stochastic component of the process ($W_t$) has constant moments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correlation function is proportional to $e^{-\gamma\tau} = e^{-\gamma|t-t'|}$, see e.g. [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physa.2012.12.011) for a more verbose definition than the MathWorld page. And this is indeed stationary under a translation $t \mapsto t + dt$ of the time.